# Como configurar o .htaccess para bloquear acesso direto a todos os diretórios exceto o public

Tags: jquery, htaccess, apache, http

Tenho um problema com relação a configurar o .htaccess, eu quero que o usuário tenha acesso somente a pasta public, com isso eu criei um .htaccess na raiz do sistema bloqueando acesso a todas as pastas e arquivos, e um na pasta public dando acesso.

O problema é que o .htaccess bloqueia o jQuery de fazer requisições fora da pasta public, quero saber se tem alguma maneira de permitir que essas requisições acontecem.

Meu site ta organizado assim:

```
site:
/public
/usuarios
/config
.htaccess
```

o .htacess na raiz tem somente o code:

```
Allow from all
```

o da pasta public tem:

```
Allow from all
```

Comment: E que requisições são essas que o jQuery faz?

Comment: validação de formulário, só que por causa do .htaccess, retorna o erro 403

Comment: Se você faz requisições assincronas para a pasta `/usuarios`, então o que você quer é bloquear a pasta `/config`, não? O que você tem na pasta `/usuarios` deve ser uma API que é consultada, ela deve ser exposta de alguma forma, importa se ela foi acessada assincronamente com o jQuery ou direto pela URL do browser?

Comment: eu vou ter arquivos .json na pasta config e usuarios, que eu não quero que o usuário consiga acessar diretamente, por isso o bloqueio, mais eu preciso que o jquery consiga fazer requisições pra arquivos .php nessa pasta. E esse php faça as interações com o .json